# Sketch the graph of a function with the following properties

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, curves

I have the following question here...

> Sketch the graph of a function f that has the following given properties.
> Identify critical numbers, local extrema, in
> ection points, and asymptotes.
> Assume $f$ and its derivatives exist and are continuous everywhere unless the contrary is implied or explicitly stated.
> a) $f(0)=0, f(2)=3, f(4)$ is undefined, $f(7)=0, f(10)=1.$
> b) $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 4^-} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 4^+} f(x) = \infty.$
> c) $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} (f(x)+x+2)=0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x)-2)=0.$
> d) $f'(x)>0$ on $(0,2)$ and $(7,\infty)$; $f'(x)<0$ on $(-\infty,0),(2,4)$ and $(4,7)$.
> e) $f'(0)$ is undefined and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^-} f'(x)=0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)=\infty.$
> f) $\displaystyle f''(x)>0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(4,10)$; $f''(x)<0$ on $(0,4)$ and $(10,\infty).$

So I summarized the following information...

$f(x)$ is increasing from $(0,2),(7,\infty).$
$f(x)$ is decreasing from $(-\infty,0),(2,4),(4,7).$
There is a vertical tangent at $x=0$.
$f(x)$ is concave up from $(-\infty,0),(4,10).$
$f(x)$ is concave down from $(0,4),(10,\infty).$

There are no points of inflection.

There is a minimum at $x=0$ and $x=7$.
The is a maximum at $x=2$.
There is a slant asymptote of $y=-x-2$ and $y=2$.
There is a vertical asymptote of $x=4.$

I got a graph that looks something like this. Can someone verify if this is correct?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Quick read. The function you drew is not decreasing in $(-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: It's going down though isn't it? Increasing would be if it suddenly tended to infinity.

Comment: Your picture shows a local minimum at about $x = -1$. Between there and the origin it is increasing. (I haven't read the requirements or your answer carefully. Maybe this is OK. It just doesn't match the words you wrote.(

Comment: Your function should have a minimum at $x=7$, not $x=10$. Notice that $x=7$ is a critical point. You wrote it down but it's incorrect on your graph

Comment: Also, I believe your limits for $f'(x)$ at zero are incorrect. This would also fix it being increasing for some region in $(-\infty,0)$

Comment: How would I do that? Doesn't that just mean there's a vertical tangent at $0$?